# Arrays outside main methods?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, nullpointerexception

I am new to java programming. And I am a bit stuck with print out arrays inside methods.Suppose, I have

```
public class A{
    private static String a;
    private static char[] c;
    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args){
     word=sc.next();
     char[] c = word.toCharArray();
     System.out.println(c);
     System.out.println(c.length)
     printIt();
    }
    private static void printIt(){
     System.out.println(c);
       }
     }
```

This example fails to compile and gives out a NullPointerException.
But for a given command line input like "test".It does print out the "test" and the length as "4".However when I try to print out the array using a method it fails to print it.

I know the array is getting initialized and populated with characters as it's printing out 4.

Could anyone tell me why it works inside the main method and why it doesn't work inside a private method?

Comment: You never initialize the `private static char[] c` but create a new local variable in the main method. Remove `char[]` from `char[] c = word.toCharArray();` in the main method

Comment: @PrasadKharkar derp, so it is. Ignore me.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar, even I was half right, there was a local variable defined in main method :D

Comment: oh and `word` has not been declared

Comment: ... I'm not sure how you can get a runtime exception (NPE) if your program doesn't compile.  Note that static mutable state has some major problems, and should be avoided as much as possible; if you need the data in something else, you should be passing it as parameters.

Comment: Why is everything static? Did you not know how to use variables in your main method w/o thinking they all need to be static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of errors:

```
word=sc.next();
```

You need to declare word first:

```
String word=sc.next();
```

Or maybe?

```
a = sc.next();
c = a.toCharArray();
```

You redeclare `c`, hiding attribute and causing the **`NullPointerException`** when you call method `printIt()`!:

```
char[] c = word.toCharArray();  // this is a method attribute not the class one!
```

Also a missing semicolon `;`

```
System.out.println(c.length);
//                          ↑ here
```

---

**FINAL RESULT:**

```
public class A{
    private static String a;
    private static char[] c;
    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        a = sc.nextLine();
        c = a.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(c);          // 1
        System.out.println(c.length);   // 2
        printIt();                      // 3
        sc.close();
    }

    private static void printIt() {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

**INPUT:**

```
asdsadsadsadsads
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
asdsadsadsadsads  // 1
16                // 2
asdsadsadsadsads  // 3
```

Answer (score 2):

By using `char[] c`, you redeclare it inside the method, it isn't the same as the one on the class level. Use  simply `c = word.toCharArray()`

Answer (score 1):

First there are some errors in your code

line 6: you have to define word (i think `String word = sc.next();`

line 9: `System.out.println(c.length);`

Then your method doesn't work because your datamember is still empty, you have created a new variable with the same name. Try to sobstitute line 10 with: `c = word.toCharArray();`